# git clone did not give me all branches

Tags: git, bitbucket

I just cloned a repo from bitbucket.  For some reason, My local repo does not have all the branches in it.  It only has `master`.  I tried `git checkout origin/develop` and ended up with a detached HEAD. `git fetch` gives nothing.

I was able to solve it by creating a new branch manually with `git checkout -b develop`, then executing `git pull origin develop`, but I can't remember ever having to do that before.  Usually I can just sync branches from my remotes.

What's going on?

Comment: It would be enough to `git checkout develop`. Post output of `git branch -r` - you should see `origin/develop` on the list.

Comment: `git checkout develop` did nothing. I was still on `master`

Comment: By doing `git checkout origin/develop` you check out a *remote* branch.

Comment: How do you check it? What does `git branch` show?

Comment: did you tried `git fetch origin`? then checkout

Comment: `git branch` showed just master. I did just successfully checkout another branch with `git checkout foo`.  I think something must have been wrong with my `develop` branch.

Answer (score 3):

You *did* get all the branches, just not in the form you realized.

What you wanted, as [Arkadiusz Drabczyk said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983535/git-clone-did-not-give-me-all-branches#comment82935906_47983535), was to run `git checkout develop`, which invokes a special shortcut option inside Git—but by running `git checkout -b develop` earlier, you broke the shortcut option. :-)

Here's how the whole thing works.  It's based on *remote-tracking names*, which are names like `origin/master` and `origin/develop`.  They have a longer spelling, a sort of full name—instead of just `origin/master`, you can type in `refs/remotes/origin/master`, for instance—but why type the longer name when the shorter one will do?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Maybe the full name is useful for when you're angry or upset, like when the Stella android starts up: [HARCOURT FENTON MUDD!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ag1EbxYKh_4)

---

#### Cloning is shorthand for some more-basic commands

Running:

`git clone url`

(or the same with a target directory option) is essentially the same as running a bunch of separate commands, most (but not all) being Git commands:

1. `mkdir some-directory && cd some-directory && git init`

   The directory name here is based on the *`url`* argument: e.g., if you `git clone ssh://web.site/path/to/foo.git` you get a directory named `foo`.  The result at this point is a completely-empty repository, with no branches and no commits; but it does have a configuration.
2. `git remote add origin url`

   This adds a "remote" to the configuration.  The remote's associatd URL is *`url`*.  The remote's associated `fetch` line—the configured value for `remote.origin.fetch`—is set to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.
3. There may be some extra `git config` commands here (if you add `-c` options to your `git clone`, or use some of the other clone options like `--bare`).  In your case there aren't any here, but I include this on general principles.
4. `git fetch origin`

   This has your Git call up the Git at the now-configured *`url`* and obtain from that Git, all of its branches and tags.  Note that this is the same as any other `git fetch origin` command you might run.
5. `git checkout master`

   It's possible to get Git to use other branch names than `master` here, but `master` is the most common and most likely.  You can control what `git checkout` command `git clone` runs yourself, but if you don't, you get controlled by the repository you are cloning: *they* say which branch to check out.  If they haven't done anything special, they will say "check out `master`", so this last step will check out `master`.

#### Git's `fetch` *renames* their branches

Note that during step 4, `git fetch origin` obtains from the other Git a list of all its branch names, and their corresponding commit hash IDs.  (To see these directly, without using `git fetch`, run `git ls-remote origin`.)  But `git fetch` doesn't save those branch names as *your* branch names, because your branch names are *yours*.  Saving *theirs* could mess with your work!  So what `git fetch` does, by default, is to save their branch names as your *remote-tracking names*.

If they have a branch named `master`, your Git changes this name—the full name is `refs/heads/master`; `master` is just the short version—to read instead `refs/remotes/origin/master`, the full name of the shorter `origin/master`.  If they have a `develop`, you get an `origin/develop`, and so on.

In other words, for every *branch name* *`branch`* that *they* (`origin`) have, you get a *remote-tracking name*, spelled `origin/branch`.  The *hash IDs* for each commit carry across unchanged, but the *names* change.  If you look back at step 2 above, when `git clone` added the remote named `origin`, you'll see exactly how it is that Git knows to make this particular substitution.  The important thing, though, is that it does make the substitution.

Hence, when your clone process finishes, you still have ***no branches at all.***  And yet, your `git clone` runs `git checkout master`, and somehow, that *works*.

#### The `git checkout` command is fancy

If you ask your Git to check out a branch by name, and you don't *have* a branch by that name, your Git won't just say: *Sorry, I don't know that name.*  Instead, your Git will look at all of your *remote-tracking names*.

Since you have run `git clone` (and maybe some `git fetch`-es since then for good measure), you have the remote-tracking name `origin/master`, and all the other remote-tracking names that your `git fetch` step created or updated.  Your Git scans through all of them.  If it finds any that look a lot like `master`, or whatever branch you asked to check out, your Git will say to itself: *Aha, I found **exactly one** matching name: `origin/master`.  You must want me to **create** `master`, using the same commit that I see under `origin/master`.*

This is a "do what I mean" (or *DWIM*) trick that Git uses when you run `git checkout name` but don't *have* a branch named *name*.  It is shorthand for `git checkout -b name origin/name`.

This won't work if you have both an `origin/develop` and a `remote2/develop`, for instance, because your Git will find *two* matching names.  But to get a `remote2/develop`, you'd have to run `git remote add remote2 another-url` and then `git fetch remote2`.  If you haven't added another remote, you can't get two suitable remote-tracking `.../develop`s.

But it also won't work for `develop` if you've already created a local branch named `develop`, because now `git checkout develop` will just check out the local develop.  You already have it!  There's no need—and no ability—to create a *new* one with the fancy DWIM code.

#### One last caveat

The `git checkout` command will only let you get "on" a *local* branch.  Once you have a local branch named `develop`, or create it with `git checkout`, the `git checkout` command will set things up so that your *current branch* is the one named `develop`.  After that succeeds, running `git status` will say:

```
On branch develop
```

and then print the rest of the status.

A remote-tracking name, such as `origin/develop`, won't work for this.  Instead, Git will give you that "detached HEAD" mode you saw.  Git will check out the *commit*, but you will be on no branch at all.

To exit this "detached HEAD" mode, you simply have to `git checkout` some branch that *does* exist, or that can and will be created by the DWIM code.